# What are the philosophical differences between Vishishtadvaita Vedanta and Shivadvaita Vedanta?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, vishishtadvaita, shivadvaita

Vishishtadvaita, as we know, is a Vedantic philosophy propogated by the renowned Sripad Ramanujacharya. The philosophy is subscribed mainly by Sri Vaishnavas, Ramanandi Vaishnavas and Swaminarayan Vaishnavas.

On the other hand, Shivadvaita is another Vedantic philosophy, propagated by the Shaivite philosopher, Srikantha Shivacharya and followed by the Shaiva Siddhanta sect.

Now, often Srikantha Shivacharya is accused of copying Sripad Ramanujacharya's Vishishtadvaita philosophy and modifying it slightly to suit Shaiva philosophy as the two philosophies are almost identical in nature. So I want to know are there any philosophical differences between Ramanuja's Vishishtadvaita and Srikantha's Shivadvaita?

One glaring difference between the two philosophies I see, is Ramanuja posits Brahman as exclusively Vishnu while Srikantha sees Brahman as exclusively Shiva. So are there any other differences between the two philosophies?

Comment: I wonder why they have a word for Brahman if it is exclusively Shiva or Vishnu. .

Comment: In His commentary of Brahma-Sutra, Srikantha writes: 'Bheda-abheda-kalpanam vishistadvaitam sadhyamah'. Can someone copy with such openness?

Comment: The concept of Akasha-Sarira Brahma and Chid-aakasha or Chit-Shakti seems an original concept of Srikantha.

Comment: @PeterJ Because each name of the names describes contextual/aspected meanings as well, I can have many names based on my adjectival nature in context and still possess an identity that is singularly supreme.

Comment: @PeterJ Vishnu is not limited to one name. Same applies to Shiva.

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri - Yes, that was my point. No need for 'exclusivity'.of names. The 99 names of God and all that. .   .

Comment: @PeterJ I think you missed my point. Nevermind.

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri - If so my apologies. ...